# Can you run away without losing against a monster?

Tags: munchkin

In Munchkin, I found the following for running away ([source](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf))

> If nobody will help you . . . or if somebody tries to help, and your fellow
>   party members interfere so the two of you still cannot win . . . you must Run
>   Away. You don’t get any levels or Treasure. You don’t even get to Loot the
>   Room. And you don’t always escape unharmed . . .
>   Roll the die. You escape on a 5 or more. Some Class and Race abilities
>   and some Treasures make it easier or harder to Run Away from all
>   monsters. And some monsters give you a bonus or penalty to
>   your roll for that monster only.

However, it is not clear to me if you can run away if you would win.

For example, if you don't have cards on your hand and if you have "die hard" ("Hart im Nehmen" in German; it prevents you from losing your stuff when you die) you might actually want to die. Or if you are forced to help somebody and you can run away easily, you might rather try that.

Can you choose to run away even if you would win?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot run away if you are winning with just your equipment. From the [Munchkin FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/):

> **Q. Do I have to kill a monster? Even if I'm winning, can I just choose to Run Away?**
>   A. You can't Run Away if you are winning with what you have in play. However, you are not required to play one-shot cards, negative Monster Enhancers, etc., to beat it, even if you could win handily. So, in that sense, you would be able to choose to Run Away.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! I'll accept in five minutes (I cannot accept earlier, I'm sorry.)